# Replace all occurences of "-" between numbers with ":" in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have a string which looks like this:

```
1,87-99,88:12,sds-554,sdsd,787,99-145
```

If a "-" appears in the middle of 2 numbers, I want to change it to a ":".
What is the shortest way to do this in javascript? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
text='1,87-99,88:12,sds-554,sdsd,787,99-145';
tex2=text.replace(/(\d)-(\d)/g,'$1:$2');
console.log(tex2);
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/bingjie2680/Wcptr/

Answer (score 1):

Here's my variant.

```
var a = '1,87-99,88:12,sds-554,sdsd,787,99-145'
var b = a.replace(/(\d)-(\d)/g,'$1:$2')
```

`$1` and `$2` puts matched digits back into string.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
'1,87-99,88:12,sds-554,sdsd,787,99-145'.replace(/(\d)-(\d)/g, '$1:$2'));​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZK9Mj/

Answer (score -1):

```
var a = '1,87-99,88:12,sds-554,sdsd,787,99-145'
var b = a.replace(/(\d)-(\d)/g, '$1:$2');
```

"b" will give you what you want

Comment: In the example only 87-89 and 99-145 should be replaced. sds-554 should not be replaced.

Comment: You're removing the numbers, not just replacing the hyphen.